# Question about the difference between radix trees and patricia trees

Tags: data-structures, trees

I've already done some research on this topic, but it still isn't quite clear to me.

According to [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/63060/81388) patricia trees are radix trees with $r = 2$. Every patricia tree I've seen so far is used to store alphanumeric symbols. Assuming that there are used 8 bits to represent one symbol, $r$ is the number of bits compared and the radix of a radix tree is $2^r$ shouldn't the radix of a patricia tree be $2^8 = 256$?

If you have a look at a PATRICIA Tree with the following inputs (in this order):

- smile
- smiled
- smiles

According to the linked post a Patricia tree should then look like this:

```
smile - - - smiled - - - smiles
```

But intuitively (by the alphanumeric representation) it should look like this

```
       d
      /
smile 
      \
       s
```

Comment: Not necessarily. If you know that the data is alphanumeric, you can use a smaller radix.

Comment: I understand the referenced post differently. A symbol may have 8 bits, but in Patricia trees you can split at any one of these bits, thus each split still has only at most two children. If you store all 256 permutations of a single symbol, your tree is 8 levels deep and 128 node wide.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  if you have another look at the post, there is an example of a patricia tree. This tree is correct for the binary representation but not for the raw alphanumeric. Any ideas how to explain this?

Comment: A Patricia tree has radix 2. It treats its input as a stream of bits.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I updated my post to explain what I don't understand

Comment: A Patricia tree considers a binary encoding of its contents, and uses it to construct a radix 2 tree. As far as it is concerned, there is no such thing as a letter - everything is a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree#History):

> PATRICIA trees are radix trees with radix equals 2, which means that each bit of the key is compared individually and each node is a two-way (i.e., left versus right) branch.

According to Wikipedia, *Patricia* is just a "brand name" coined by Donald R. Morrison, standing for *Practical Algorithm To Retrieve Information Coded In Alphanumeric*.

Patricia trees thus accept their input in the form of binary strings. If the input is a word, then it is first encoded in binary.

As for the smile/smiled/smiles example, it is explained in the linked post – each of these words is encoded as a binary string, and this is what the Patricia tree sees. It is completely unaware of the semantic interpretation of the bitstring as an alphanumeric word.

Comment: Does that mean a radix tree with r = 256 (as described in my question) would represent a tree in the correct form for alphanumeric? (assuming a symbol need 8 bits)

Comment: A radix tree with radix $r \neq 2$ is not a Patricia tree, since a Patricia tree has radix 2.

Comment: I mean a radix tree with r = 256 should be the right thing I'm looking for?

Comment: Only you know what you're looking for.